# Mysql: How do I GRANT SELECT on a demo database to all users

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I have a demo mysql database the I would like all users to be able to see.

How do I grant SELECT on this one database to all the mysql users?

I tried:

GRANT SELECT ON demodb.* TO ''@localhost;

This seemed to run, but no change on the visability of the demodb database.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
INSERT INTO mysql.db(host, User, Db, select_priv)
  SELECT host, user, 'demodb', 'Y' FROM  mysql.user;
```

Then run 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES;' to apply privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Better still, your original solution should have worked, and doesn't require an extra line for every new user, but you needed to flush privileges. I used this for setting up my global DB.

```
INSERT INTO mysql.db (host,user,db,Select_priv,Execute_priv) VALUE
('%','','demodb','Y','Y');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```